# How to get position of swipe gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am trying to get the position of swipe using below code, but it returns same position no matter where I swipe on the screen.

**CODE:**

```
-(void) recognizeTapGesture : (UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender  {

    CGPoint event;
    event = [sender locationInView: nil ];

    NSLog(@"Tap Detected (%f,%f) %lu",event.x,event.y,(unsigned long)sender.numberOfTouches);
} 

-(void) recognizeLeftSwipeGesture : (UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)sender  {

    CGPoint event;
    event = [sender locationInView: nil ];

    NSLog(@"Left Swipe Detected (%f,%f) %lu",event.x,event.y,(unsigned long)sender.numberOfTouches);

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    _TapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(recognizeTapGesture:)];

    _LeftswipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(recognizeLeftSwipeGesture:) ];

    _LeftswipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

    _LeftswipeGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    _TapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [[self window] addGestureRecognizer:_LeftswipeGesture];

    [[self window] addGestureRecognizer:_TapGesture];

    return YES;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Tap Detected (286.500000,460.500000) 1
Left Swipe Detected (0.000000,0.000000) 1
```

Is this code sufficient, to find position of a swipe. I want to know how to find position of swipe in objective-c. Is there something I am missing ?. Why is the number of touches always 1. When I set *minimum touches required* more than one, swipe is not detected.

Comment: Show the code you implemented for Tap Gesture.

Comment: @Mr.UB , I put in the complete code. Is the above code enough for getting the position of swipe gestures. I have not handled **touchesBegan, touchesEnded, etc.** Moreover why is the number of touches always one?When I change **numberoftouchesrequired** to 2, it does not get detected.

Comment: Change `event = [sender locationInView: nil ];` to `event = [sender locationInView: self.view ];` and see what happens.

Comment: @Mr.UB , Does not work. Is there something missing? How would you do it to find position of swipeGesture in objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why exactly this is the case, but tapGesture gets location at window level, while swipeGesture gets location from View level. Hence in case of swipeGesture the location retrieval function becomes this

`event = [sender locationInView: currentviewController.view ];`

To get currentviewcontroller, we can either create function to get it and use above code or simply define the function and gesturerecognizer in UIViewController and use this,

`event = [sender locationInView: self.view ];`